# Excel VBA code to set x-axis to minimum and maximum value in plotted range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code (below) that sets the min and max x-axis values to a specified cell (B4 and B15). However, I have many plots in my workbook, and all need a different min and max x-axis range. I want a VBA code that goes to the plotted x-axis range and then finds the min and max value in that range and sets the axis to those values. How can I alter the code below to do that?

```
Sub Resize_Fonts()
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim Cht As ChartObject

For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each Cht In Sht.ChartObjects
        Cht.Chart.ChartArea.Font.Size = 9
        Cht.Chart.ChartArea.Font.Name = "Cambria"
        Cht.Chart.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlNone
        Cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
        Cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Range("B4").Value
        Cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Range("B15").Value


    Next Cht
Next Sht

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If the min and max are always within the range `B14:B15` on `Sht` you can use:

```
Cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = worksheetfunction.Min(Sht.Range("B4:B15"))
Cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = worksheetfunction.Max(Sht.Range("B4:B15"))
```

Comment: What if the range I want the x-axis is not all in column B, but is spaced out in a pattern. For example, on one sheet I have x-axis values in column B, K, P, U, Z, AE, AJ, AT, etc. so column B + 9. I would want a loop that goes through one sheet, then starts over again at the next sheet. Then the next sheet is the same pattern. How do I write that loop?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `dim count as long` and put your min / max values in adjacent columns. Then increment your `count` in your `For each` loop and use `Cells([row], [n+] count).value` to get the cell value.
By the way, You can use:

```
With cht.Chart 
    [...]
End with
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the WorksheetFunction.Min for this.

```
    Cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = WorksheetFunction.Min(Columns(2))
    Cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns(2))
```

This assumes the x-axis values are in column 2.

Comment: What if I want to look through each chart in a sheet such that I do column 2, then column 2+9, etc. I want to do that the same for all my charts in every sheet.

Comment: You can have these set up using With statements, where With Sht.Cht.Chart is used.  That should allow, when going through the For Each sections, it to apply to all loops.

Comment: Regarding the additional columns, you should be able to use a range such as .Min(Range(Columns(2),Columns(9))).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `With Cht.Chart` statement, it will shorten and clear your coding style.

When looking for the `Min` and `Max` values in Column B, you need to make sure you fully qualify the `Range`, by adding `Sht.Range`.

**Code**

```
Sub Resize_Fonts()

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim Cht As ChartObject

For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each Cht In Sht.ChartObjects
        With Cht.Chart
            .ChartArea.Font.SIZE = 9
            .ChartArea.Font.Name = "Cambria"
            .cartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlNone
            .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
            .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = WorksheetFunction.Min(Sht.Range("B1:B" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row))
            .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sht.Range("B1:B" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row))
        End With
    Next Cht
Next Sht

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments, as I first said with my other unregistered account, you can use this method:

```
Sub Resize_Fonts()
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim Cht As ChartObject
Dim count as Long 

count = 2 ' For column B
For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each Cht In Sht.ChartObjects
        With Cht.Chart
            .ChartArea.Font.Size = 9
            .ChartArea.Font.Name = "Cambria"
            .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlNone
            .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
            .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Sht.Cells(4, count).Value
            .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Sht.Cells(15, count).Value
        End with
        count = count + n ' with n your "pattern"
    Next Cht
    count = 2 ' reset the count when changing sheet
Next Sht

End Sub
```

This assume values are always row 4 and row 15.

Comment if you have any other queries

Comment: This seems exactly what I want. However, when I run this, I get a Type Mismatch error occurring in the line .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Sht.Cells(4, count).Value

Comment: Can you give me an example of your used values? B4 and B15. Is it for the first chart, second one, or more? First sheet, second sheet or more?

Comment: So I have count defined as a long, then count = 5. I moved my columns to that each column I want to grab is a multiple of 5 to make it easier. then I have these lines in the code:               .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Sht.Cells(4, count).Value
            .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Sht.Cells(23, count).Value

Comment: Okay, so what values do you put in your cells E4 and E23? Can you check in which sheet and which chart your error comes from? (first chart of first sheet, second chart of first sheet, first chart of second sheet, ...) Did you change the parameter "n"?